# Bash variable substitution with json string as variable within larger json object

Tags: bash, json, aws

I am having trouble getting the AWS cli working nicely with a bash variable. The AWS cli command takes in a JSON string as a parameter. However, within this json string I am using a variable `$SCHEMA_DEFINITION` which itself is a JSON string. For some reason the double quotes are being removed from `$SCHEMA_DEFINITION` and making it invalid JSON. How can I preserve these quotes and still produce a valid AWS command?

```
aws glue create-schema --cli-input-json '{"RegistryId": {"RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"},"SchemaName": "'$modelClassName'","DataFormat": "AVRO","Compatibility": "FULL_ALL","SchemaDefinition": "'"$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"'"}'
```

Gives the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateSchema operation: Schema definition of AVRO data format is invalid: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{name:hello}"
```

Here is how I set the variable: `SCHEMA_DEFINITION={"name":"Hello"}`

Comment: What exact value do you need the variable to have? Should it be `{name:Hello}` or `{"name":"Hello"}`?

Comment: @terdon I would need ```{"name":"Hello"}```, the first is not valid json for the command  which is what the error seems to be telling me as far as I can tell

Comment: Is the service expecting that value to be a JSON object, or a JSON object encoded as a string (`"{\"name\":\"Hello\"}"`)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried setting ```SCHEMA_DEFINITION="{\"name\":\"Hello\"}"```

Then with command:

```aws glue create-schema --cli-input-json '{"RegistryId": {"RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"},"SchemaName": "'$modelClassName'","DataFormat": "AVRO","Compatibility": "FULL_ALL","SchemaDefinition": "'$SCHEMA_DEFINITION'"}'```

And it tells me invalid JSON ```Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON received.```

Comment: @MarcoOrlando Yes, that should have been `SCHEMA_DEFINITION='{\"name\":\"Hello\"}'`.  Note the single quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah ok that seems to work! Now I just need to figure out how to find and replace in the shell and I should be good. Find and replace the double quotes with backslash double quote.

Comment: @MarcoOrlando You should not need to. See my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda the example I provided for my question was a simplified version of my real use case just to isolate 1 issue at a time. I cant really hard code in the string as above, so what I did was    
```SCHEMA_DEFINITION=${SCHEMA_DEFINITION//\"/\\\"}``` to change all quotes to backslash quotes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If one of the answers solved your issue, consider accepting it. If you have a solution different from all answers, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit, which added the answer to the text of the question. If you have an answer to your question, consider adding it as a proper answer, not as an edit to the question. As I mentioned in my previous comment, this allows you to later accept your solution, which will mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON you seem to want to create should contain a JSON object encoded as a JSON string as the value for the `SchemaDefinition` key.  You also seem to want to include the value of the shell variable `modelClassName` as the value for the `SchemaName` key.

You can create your JSON using `jq` like so:

```bash
json=$(
    jq -n -c \
        --arg SchemaName "$modelClassName" \
        --arg SchemaDefinition '{"name": "Hello"}' \
        '{"RegistryId":{"RegistryName":"hxp-schema-registry"},"DataFormat":"AVRO","Compatibility":"FULL_ALL"} + $ARGS.named'
)
```

or, for easier reading,

```bash
json=$(
    jq -n -c \
        --arg SchemaName "$modelClassName" \
        --arg SchemaDefinition '{"name": "Hello"}' '
    {
      "RegistryId": {
        "RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"
      },
      "DataFormat": "AVRO",
      "Compatibility": "FULL_ALL"
    } + $ARGS.named'
)
```

or even,

```bash
schema_json=$(
    jq -n -c --arg name 'hello' '$ARGS.named'
)

json=$(
    jq -n -c \
        --arg SchemaName "$modelClassName" \
        --arg SchemaDefinition "$schema_json" '
    {
      "RegistryId": {
        "RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"
      },
      "DataFormat": "AVRO",
      "Compatibility": "FULL_ALL"
    } + $ARGS.named'
)
```

This correctly encodes both the schema definition JSON object and the model class name as JSON strings and inserts them in the appropriate place in the JSON document.

Then call your command:

```bash
aws glue create-schema --cli-input-json "$json"
```

Answer (score 2):

The shell is eating your quotes. Quotes are special for the shell, it needs them to protect other special characters like spaces:

```
$ var=aaa bb cc
bash: bb: command not found
terdon@tpad ~ $ var="aaa bb cc"
terdon@tpad ~ $ echo "$var"
aaa bb cc
```

So, in your case, the shell thinks the quites are there to protect the value so it doesn't save them as part of the variable's value:

```
$ SCHEMA_DEFINITION={"name":"Hello"}
$ echo "$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"
{name:Hello}
```

But don't worry, there's an easy fix! You can use single quotes around the variable definition:

```
$ SCHEMA_DEFINITION='{"name":"Hello"}'
$ echo "$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"
{"name":"Hello"}
```

Or you can escape the quotes:

```
$ SCHEMA_DEFINITION={\"name\":\"Hello\"}
$ echo "$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"
{"name":"Hello"}
```

Or you can use the `printf` builtin command:

```
$ printf -v SCHEMA_DEFINITION '{"%s":"%s"}' "name" "Hello"
$ echo "$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"
{"name":"Hello"}
```

Or you can use the [`jo(1)`](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) utility:

```
SCHEMA_DEFINITION=$(jo name=hello)
```

I would even suggest building the entire thing as a variable first:

```
schema_definition='{"name":"Hello"}'
modelClassName='"thisModel"'
json_string='{"RegistryId": {"RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"},"SchemaName":'
json_string="$json_string $modelClassName"
json_string="$json_string"' "DataFormat": "AVRO","Compatibility": "FULL_ALL","SchemaDefinition": '"$schema_definition"
```

Which results in:

```
$ echo "$json_string"
{"RegistryId": {"RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"},"SchemaName": "thisModel" "DataFormat": "AVRO","Compatibility": "FULL_ALL","SchemaDefinition": {"name":"Hello"}
```

So you can now just do:

```
aws glue create-schema --cli-input-json "$json_string"
```

Comment: As far as I can see, they are actually using the variable in a double-quoted context already. I'm assuming the value should be a string, i.e. a JSON object encoded as a string.

Comment: I have tried this but now I get the error ```Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON received.```

Comment: @MarcoOrlando see updated answer, does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Terdon is right in that your json variable was set incorrectly but you are also passing it to the command incorrectly.

You are passing:

```
{
    "RegistryId": {
        "RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"
    },
    "SchemaName": "'$modelClassName'",
    "DataFormat": "AVRO",
    "Compatibility": "FULL_ALL",
    "SchemaDefinition": "'"$SCHEMA_DEFINITION"'"
}
```

Which would expand to:

```
{
    "RegistryId": {
        "RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"
    },
    "SchemaName": "'$modelClassName'",
    "DataFormat": "AVRO",
    "Compatibility": "FULL_ALL",
    "SchemaDefinition": "{"name":"Hello"}"
}
```

Note specifically `"{"name":"Hello"}"`.

I would recommend using a heredoc for this but either way you need to remove the extra double quotes around the `{}`.

```
read -rd json <<EOF
{
    "RegistryId": {
        "RegistryName": "hxp-schema-registry"
    },
    "SchemaName": "$modelClassName",
    "DataFormat": "AVRO",
    "Compatibility": "FULL_ALL",
    "SchemaDefinition": $SCHEMA_DEFINITION
}
EOF
```

Or using jo(1):

```
json=$(jo RegistryId=$(jo RegistryName=hxp-schema-registry) \
SchemaName=$modelClassName \
DataFormat=AVRO \
Compatibility=FULL_ALL \
SchemaDefinition=$SCHEMA_DEFINITION)
```

Then you would call your command with a variable:

```
aws glue create-schema --cli-input-json "$json"
```

---

Also I recommend https://jsonlint.com/ for validating your json inputs if you are running into issues like this.